# Will React Native consider adding true CSS?

Tags: css, react-native

At first glance, React Native appears to have CSS support.  But users quickly learn that it's not even close.  There is no css parsing, no selectors, and no 'cascading style'.  Everything is basically POJOs.

I'm on a team building a React Native app and every new developer has been confused by this.  The styling, IMO, needs major improvement.  I would like it to be closer to the web, supporting such things as:

1. .css file parsing
2. class and element selectors.  I want `<View className="container" />`
3. style resolution like the web
4. maybe pseudoselectors

There isn't anything like this on the [roadmap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Roadmap).  I'm shocked it isn't under discussion.  I'm considering tackling this problem, but I want to be sure it's not already underway or something people don't want.

So, I'd like to know:
1) are there any plans to implement something like this and 2) is this desirable?

I'm unsure if SO is the forum for this, but it was recommended in the RN readme.  If it's inappropriate for SO, please point me to a better place rather than just flagging it as off topic or whatever.

By the way, I've already started work on this.  My plan is to use WebKit for CSS parsing and resolution.  Then I'll have to modify the RN code to add className and tag name support, as well as integrate with WebKit for applying the styles at render time.  The end goal is to get this integrated into the framework, but at first I'd prefer to develop as a separate library, potentially (hopefully not) having to fork or patch RN core.

I only need a small portion of the massive WebKit code base.  If anyone is or knows someone familiar with WebKit, I'd love some help.

Comment: If you really want to discuss this, Product Pains is probably a better forum: https://productpains.com/product/react-native/ - that said, I'm pretty sure the answer is no, as the premise that cascading, external style sheets are superior is pretty questionable

Comment: I don't think it should be part of RN core. RN is not web. Now styling is very simple and fast most because it's based on pure js and can be transformed to pure platform styles. Anyway styling with css can be developed as external library/transpiler.

Comment: Thanks @jevakallio I took it to productpains.com.  As to your opinions, thanks but I disagree.  "RN is not web" is technically true, yet considering it runs JS and has FlexBox and 'Style Sheets', I would say RN uses web technologies, and one of the most beloved web techs is CSS.  Use RN in a team setting and you'll maybe reconsider your position when half of them are confused by RN's half-baked styling.

Comment: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/true-css is my post by the way